# What is the equivalent of buf.readUInt16LE(offset) in Python

Tags: python, node.js

I am looking for the equivalent of this function (from node.js) in Python

[buf.readUInt16LE(offset)](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuint16le_offset)

> offset:  Number of bytes to skip before starting to read. Must satisfy 0 <= offset <= buf.length - 2.
>
> Returns: 
> Reads an unsigned 16-bit integer from buf at the specified offset with specified endian format (readUInt16BE() returns big endian, readUInt16LE() returns little endian).

Example:

```
const buf = Buffer.from([0x12, 0x34, 0x56]);

console.log(buf.readUInt16BE(0).toString(16));
// Prints: 1234
console.log(buf.readUInt16LE(0).toString(16));
// Prints: 3412
console.log(buf.readUInt16BE(1).toString(16));
// Prints: 3456
console.log(buf.readUInt16LE(1).toString(16));
// Prints: 5634
console.log(buf.readUInt16LE(2).toString(16));
// Throws ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no such functions that I'm aware of, though there may be a package that does this.
Using the standard library utilities, you can use `struct.unpack` and `io.BytesIO` for the conversion and handling of a (binary) buffer.

Below is an example (Python 3). Apologies if the lines feel a bit compact; I hope it's still straightforward to read.

```
import io
import struct

buf = io.BytesIO(bytearray([0x12, 0x34, 0x56]))

# < and > for little and big endian, H for 2-byte unsigned short.
assert format(struct.unpack(">H", buf.read(2))[0], '02x') == "1234"

# buf.seek to reset to byte 0 (1, 2) of the stream; also for file objects
buf.seek(0)
assert format(struct.unpack("<H", buf.read(2))[0], '02x') == "3412"

buf.seek(1)
assert format(struct.unpack(">H", buf.read(2))[0], '02x') == "3456"

buf.seek(1)
assert format(struct.unpack("<H", buf.read(2))[0], '02x') == "5634"

buf.seek(2)
try:
    format(struct.unpack("<H", buf.read(2))[0], '02x')
except struct.error as exc:
    assert exc.args[0] == "unpack requires a buffer of 2 bytes"
else:
    assert False, "exception failed to be raised"
```

More details at the documentation pages of the [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) and [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) modules.